# MySql - Inserir vários produtos em um pedido

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de pedido no mysql, onde nela deve ser informado o valor total do pedido, a data, id do cliente, e os produtos que foram comprados. O problema que esses produtos é da tabela produto. Gostaria de saber como faço para inserir esses vários produtos com o comando sql? Inserir apenas um produto eu sei de boas. Vou usar isso em uma aplicação Web C#, onde o cliente seleciona os produtos em um grid e confirma o pedido.

Comment: Olá @Vanderson, Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow-pt. Dê uma conferida neste link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tente incluir o máximo de informações possíveis em suas perguntas. Nesse caso, talvez detalhar a forma que o seu banco de dados foi mapeado.

Answer (score -1):

Vanderson, suponhamos que essa seja sua tabela `compras` com as seguintes colunas:

```
id, total_pedido, data, id_cliente
```

Você teria que ter uma tabela `pedido_detalhes` que tivesse as seguintes colunas:

```
idproduto, idcompra
```

Sendo assim, sempre que fosse inserido uma "**compra**", ela iria gerar um `ID` que seria salvo junto a todos os produtos comprados na tabela `pedido_detalhes`.

Comment: Entendi amigo, vlw mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: Amigo teria como mostrar como ficaria o código sql para essa inserção ? Pq fazer a inserção simples eu consigo de boas: insert into pedido (valorPedido, dataPedido, id_cliente) values (2000, '2016-02-23 00:00:00', 1). Mas como ficaria esse sql para funcionar com a tabela pedido_detalhes?